# Как получить первое значение из массива внутри json?

Tags: javascript

Есть json, где выводится такое поле

```
"image_url":"one.jpg|two.jpg|three.jpg|four.jpg",
```

Весь ответ

```
[
{
"KEYWORDS": "тест",
"LINK": "https://test.ru/",
"IMAGE_URL":"one.jpg|two.jpg|three.jpg|four.jpg"
}]
```

Как мне получить первое значение one.jpg  в переменную value.image_url

```
fetch('https://site.com/json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

        console.log(data.IMAGE_URL); //тут нужно получить 1 значение one
        
     })
    .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
```

Спасибо.

Comment: image_url !== IMAGE_URL

Comment: Поправил, это я писал тут вопрос и разный регистр случайно задействовал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let data = [{
    "KEYWORDS": "тест",
    "LINK": "https://test.ru/",
    "IMAGE_URL":"one.jpg|two.jpg|three.jpg|four.jpg"
}];

let whatINeed = data[0].IMAGE_URL.split('|')[0];
let nameWithoutExt = whatINeed.split('.')[0];
console.log(whatINeed, nameWithoutExt);
```

---

```js
let data = [{
    "KEYWORDS": "тест",
    "LINK": "https://test.ru/",
    "IMAGE_URL":"one.jpg|two.jpg|three.jpg|four.jpg"
}];

let imgUrl = data[0].IMAGE_URL;
let indexOfTheFirstDot =imgUrl.indexOf('.');
let nameWithoutExt = imgUrl.substr(0, indexOfTheFirstDot);
console.log(nameWithoutExt);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. То что прям хотел.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а если один ответ содержит этот массив, а другой нет.

    "IMAGE_URL":"one.jpg|two.jpg|three.jpg|four.jpg"


    "IMAGE_URL":"one.jpg"

Comment: @РусланЛысенко значит делайте проверку. если есть - делать что-то.

Comment: Всё, спасибо за подсказку, всё таки сделал)